Handling Nested Macro Expansions in Clang LibTooling Application
I am developing a clang libTooling application that instruments (rewrites) C code.  In order to prepare the code for the a RecursiveASTVisitor (where the final code is rewritten), I need to pre-expand all the macro invocations in the C code.  I am facing challenges with handling nested macros and function-like macros where a parameter is also a macros (I think this could be considered nested macro variant).
I implemented a partial solution by creating a MacroExpander (a clang::PPCallbacks subclass) that partially succeeds in expanding macros.
Edited Question Text
I added the following block of code to the logic that handles functionLike macro parameter expansion (This code update is also reflected in included example code) showing exactly where I need help.  Specifically, when we have a macro parameter that needs expansion, I need to relex the parameter.
std::vector<std::string> expandedMacroArgs;
for (auto argNum = 0u; argNum < Args->getNumMacroArguments(); ++argNum) {
    if (const auto* token = Args->getUnexpArgument(argNum)) {
        // Check if macro argument is an unexpanded macro
        if (Args->ArgNeedsPreexpansion(token, mPP)) {
            // @BEGIN
            // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP TO EXPAND argNum to its original expansion
            std::vector<clang::Token> tokens;
            while (token->isNot(clang::tok::eof)) {
                tokens.emplace_back(*token);
                ++token;
            }
            const auto& expandedMacroArg = tokens
                | std::views::transform([&](const auto& next) {
                        return mPP.getSpelling(next);
                    })
                | std::views::join_with(std::string(" "))
                | std::ranges::to<std::string>();
            expandedMacroArgs.emplace_back(
                expandedMacroArg);
            // @END
        }
    }
}

Examples and Expected output
Consider for example a pair of macros defined as:
#define MIN(a, b) (((a) <= (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MAX(a, b) (((a) >  (b)) ? (a) : (b))

Here are a few simple examples of expected macro expansions:

MIN(1, 7) => (((1) <= (7)) ? (1) : (7))
MAX(5, 8) => (((5) >  (8)) ? (5) : (8))
MIN(MAX(5, 8), 7) => ((((((5) > (8)) ? (5) : (8))) <= (7)) ? ((((5) > (8)) ? (5) : (8))) : (7))

The last example is nested, and can be obtained by substututing MAX(5, 8) for a in the MIN(a, b) macro. i.e:
MIN(MAX(5, 8), 7) => (((MAX(5, 8)) <= (7)) ? (MAX(5, 8)) : (7))

Partially working application
The code below includes a partially working MacroExpander class.  This expander has the nesting and macro parameter expansion limitations described earlier.  Additionally, I would like some guidance on how to correctly handle the token expansion logic.  I used a brute force approach which seems overkill where I needed to handle token pasting ## and stringizing # operators in addition to spacing around keywords & punctuation.  I am sure there has to be a better way to handle this.
The application (which I have working in Visual Studio - but it shold be cross platform is coded as follows:
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <clang/Lex/PPCallbacks.h>
#include <clang/Lex/MacroArgs.h>
#include <clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Tooling/Tooling.h>
#include <clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h>
#include <clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h>

using namespace llvm;
using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang::tooling;

namespace {
    llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");
}

namespace util {
    namespace rv = ranges::views;
    inline constexpr auto trim_front = rv::drop_while(::isspace);
    inline constexpr auto trim_back = rv::reverse | trim_front | rv::reverse;
    inline constexpr auto trim = trim_front | trim_back;

    inline std::string trim_str(const std::string& s) {
        return s | trim | ranges::to<std::string>;
    }

    inline std::vector<std::string> split (std::string& s, const char delim) {
        return ranges::actions::split(s, delim);
    }
}

/**
* The <code>MacroExpander</code> class overrides the
* <code>MacroExpands</code> method from
* <code>clang::PPCallbacks</code> to rewrite expanded macros
* back into the source before instrumentation.
*
* <p>As macros are expanded in the code, the
* <code>MacroExpands</code> function differentiates between
* function-like and object-like macros, handling their
* expansion differently. For function-like macros,
* it constructs a map of macro parameter names to their values
* and uses this map to replace the macro invocation in the
* source code with the expanded macro body, substituting
* parameter references with their corresponding values.
*/
class MacroExpander : public clang::PPCallbacks {
public:
    /**
    * Explicit constructor.
    *
    * <p>Change Preprocessor options via the returned reference returned by
    * <code>mPP.getPreprocessorOpts</code>() if necessary.
    *
    * @param rPP       [in] clang Preprocessor.
    * @param rRewriter [in] non const rewriter reference.
    */
    explicit MacroExpander(clang::Preprocessor &rPP, clang::Rewriter &rRewriter)
        : mPP(rPP)
        , mRewriter(rRewriter)
    {}

    /**
    * Hook that gets called as macros are expanded in the C source.
    *
    * @param MacroNameTok [in] The token representing the macro name.
    * @param MD           [in] Macro Definition containing all the
    *                     info about the type of macro and its
    *                     parameters.
    * @param Range        [in] Source range of the macro.
    * @param Args         [in] Optional macro arguments.
    */
    void MacroExpands(
        const clang::Token& MacroNameTok,
        const clang::MacroDefinition& MD, clang::SourceRange Range,
        const clang::MacroArgs* Args) override {
        // Get the macro name
        const auto MacroName = mPP.getSpelling(MacroNameTok);
        // Get the macro body
        std::string MacroBody;
        const auto MI = MD.getMacroInfo();
        if (!MI->isFunctionLike()) {
            // I think there is always just one token in these single
            // objectLike macros that do not contain parameters.
            for (const auto next : MI->tokens()) {
                MacroBody += mPP.getSpelling(next);
            }
#if defined MACRO_DEBUGGING
            // Print the macro name and body
            const auto debugString = std::format(
                "Macro {} expands to: {}"
                , MacroName
                , MacroBody);
            llvm::errs() << debugString << "\n";
#endif
            // TODO make sure macro expansion nesting works.
            mRewriter.ReplaceText(Range, MacroBody);
        } else {
            std::vector<std::string> expandedMacroArgs;
            for (auto argNum = 0u; argNum < Args->getNumMacroArguments(); ++argNum) {
                if (const auto* token = Args->getUnexpArgument(argNum)) {
                    // Check if macro argument is an unexpanded macro
                    if (Args->ArgNeedsPreexpansion(token, mPP)) {
                        // @BEGIN
                        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP TO EXPAND argNum to its original expansion
                        std::vector<clang::Token> tokens;
                        while (token->isNot(clang::tok::eof)) {
                            tokens.emplace_back(*token);
                            ++token;
                        }
                        const auto& expandedMacroArg = tokens
                            | std::views::transform([&](const auto& next) {
                                    return mPP.getSpelling(next);
                                })
                            | std::views::join_with(std::string(" "))
                            | std::ranges::to<std::string>();
                        expandedMacroArgs.emplace_back(
                            expandedMacroArg);
                        // @END
                    }
                }
            }

            // This is the complicated function like macro invocation.

            // hack together a map of macro parameter names to their values,
            // so we can substitute them in the macro body as we expand the tokens.
            std::vector<std::string> macroArgNames;
            for (const auto next : MI->params()) {
                macroArgNames.emplace_back(next->getName().str());
            }

            std::vector<std::string> macroArgValues;
            for (unsigned i = 0u, e = Args->getNumMacroArguments(); i != e; ++i) {
                if (const auto next = Args->getUnexpArgument(i); next) {
                    // Handle address parameters using special case logic.
                    if (next->is(clang::tok::amp)) {
                        auto addressParam = mPP.getSpelling(*next);
                        auto specialToken = next + 1;
                        while (specialToken->isNot(clang::tok::eof)) {
                            addressParam += mPP.getSpelling(*specialToken);
                            ++specialToken;
                        }
                        macroArgValues.emplace_back(addressParam);
                    } else if (next->is(clang::tok::identifier)) {
                        // check if parameter is unexpanded macro
                        if (mPP.getMacroInfo(next->getIdentifierInfo())) {
                            //auto bar = mPP.getMacroInfo(II->getReplacementToken(0);
                            //auto baz = mPP.getSpelling(bar);
                        }
                        macroArgValues.emplace_back(mPP.getSpelling(*next));
                    } else {
                        macroArgValues.emplace_back(mPP.getSpelling(*next));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Make sure we have the same number of arguments as parameters.
            if (macroArgValues.size() == macroArgNames.size()) {
                std::map<std::string, std::string> macroParamInfo;
                for (auto i = 0; i<macroArgNames.size(); ++i) {
                    macroParamInfo[macroArgNames[i]] = macroArgValues[i];
                }

                bool bStringizing = false;
                auto& SM = mPP.getSourceManager();
                for (const auto next : MI->tokens()) {
                    if (next.is(clang::tok::identifier)) {
                        // identifiers not found in our macro parameters
                        // need to be forwarded directly to the output unmodified.
                        const auto identifier = mPP.getSpelling(next);
                        if (const auto iter = macroParamInfo.find(
                            identifier); iter != macroParamInfo.cend()) {
                            MacroBody += iter->second;
                        } else {
                            MacroBody += identifier;
                        }
                        if (bStringizing) {
                            MacroBody += '"';
                            bStringizing = false;
                        } else {
                            MacroBody += " ";
                        }
                    } else if (next.is(clang::tok::hash)) {
                        // turn on bStringizing flag
                        MacroBody += '"';
                        bStringizing = true;
                    } else if (next.is(clang::tok::hashhash)) {
                        // do nothing (effectively) token pastes
                        MacroBody = util::trim_str(MacroBody);
                    } else if (next.isOneOf(
                        clang::tok::l_paren, clang::tok::r_paren,
                        clang::tok::l_brace, clang::tok::r_brace,
                        clang::tok::l_square, clang::tok::r_square,
                        clang::tok::colon, clang::tok::equal,
                        clang::tok::comma, clang::tok::semi)) {
                        // Punctuation
                        MacroBody = util::trim_str(MacroBody);
                        MacroBody += mPP.getSpelling(next);
                    } else {
                        MacroBody += mPP.getSpelling(next);
                        if (bStringizing) {
                            MacroBody += '"';
                            bStringizing = false;
                        } else {
                            MacroBody += " ";
                        }
                    }
                }

#if defined (MACRO_DEBUGGING)
                // Print the macro name and body
                // For example if macro is "#define MAX(a, b) ...",
                // commaSeparatedParams are "a, b".
                const std::vector paramVec(MI->params().begin(), MI->params().end());
                const auto& commaSeparatedParams = paramVec
                    | std::views::transform([&](const clang::IdentifierInfo* next) {
                    return next->getName().str();
                        })
                    | std::views::join_with(std::string(", "))
                    | std::ranges::to<std::string>();

                // For example if macro usage is "MAX(1, 2) ...",
                // commaSeparatedArgs are "1, 2".
                std::vector<clang::Token> argTokens;
                for (unsigned i = 0u, e = Args->getNumMacroArguments(); i != e; ++i) {
                    if (const auto next = Args->getUnexpArgument(i); next) {
                        argTokens.emplace_back(*next);
                    }
                }
                const auto& commaSeparatedArgs = argTokens
                    | std::views::transform([&](const auto& next) {
                    return mPP.getSpelling(next);
                        })
                    | std::views::join_with(std::string(", "))
                    | std::ranges::to<std::string>();
                const auto debugString = std::format(
                    "Macro {}({}) expands to: {}"
                    , MacroName
                    , commaSeparatedArgs
                    , MacroBody);
                llvm::errs() << debugString << "\n";
#endif
                // TODO make sure macro expansion nesting works.
                mRewriter.ReplaceText(Range, MacroBody );
            }
        }
    }
private:
    clang::Preprocessor& mPP;
    clang::Rewriter& mRewriter;
};

class MyFrontendAction : public clang::ASTFrontendAction {
public:
    [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(
        clang::CompilerInstance &CI, llvm::StringRef file) override {
        // Initialize the Rewriter, SourceManager and Language Options
        // from the provided compiler instance.
        mRewriter.setSourceMgr(CI.getSourceManager(), CI.getLangOpts());
        CI.getPreprocessor().addPPCallbacks(std::make_unique<
            MacroExpander>(CI.getPreprocessor(), mRewriter));
        return std::make_unique<clang::ASTConsumer>();
    }

    //! Outputs rewritten source to console.
    void EndSourceFileAction() override {
        mRewriter.getEditBuffer(mRewriter.getSourceMgr().
            getMainFileID()).write(llvm::outs());
    }
private:
    clang::Rewriter mRewriter;
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    auto ExpectedParser = CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
    if (!ExpectedParser) {
        llvm::errs() << ExpectedParser.takeError();
        return 1;
    }
    CommonOptionsParser &OptionsParser = ExpectedParser.get();
    ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(), OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());
    return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<MyFrontendAction>().get());
}

When running the application pass 'test.c --' as arguments and the output will appear on the console as shown later.
Test 'C' code containing unexpanded macros
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TRUE                    1
#define FALSE                   0
#define SEMI                    ;
#define GT                      >
#define GE                      >=
#define LT                      <
#define LE                      <=
#define NE                      !
#define MIN(a, b)               (((a) <= (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MAX(a, b)               (((a) >  (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MULTI_LINE_MACRO(a, b)  (((a) > (b)) ?  \
                                /*LHS*/pow((a), 2) :   \
                                /*RHS*/pow((b), 3) )
#define KNOT_TO_MSEC(a)     ((a)*0.514444)
#define STANDARD_GRAVITY    (9.80665)
#define LON_LIMIT           180.0000241664
#define LAT_LIMIT           (LON_LIMIT/2.0)
#define LOG(format, ...)    printf(format, __VA_ARGS__)

void
variadicFunctionTest(int count, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int num = va_arg(args, int);
        LOG("Argument %d: %d\n", i+1, num);
    }
    va_end(args);
}

void foo() {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    int t = 0;

    variadicFunctionTest(3, 1, 2, 3);

    // double bar = MULTI_LINE_MACRO(1, 3);
    double bar = MULTI_LINE_MACRO(1, 3);

    // double bar = KNOT_TO_MSEC(123.0) / STANDARD_GRAVITY;
    double foo = KNOT_TO_MSEC(123.0) / STANDARD_GRAVITY;

    // a = b > c ? d : e;
    a = b > c ? d : e;

    // a = (b > c) ? (a LT b) ? c : d : TRUE;
    a = (b > c) ? (a LT b) ? c : d : TRUE;

    // a = b GT c  ? d : e;
    a =  b GT c  ? d : e;

    // a = (b GT c) ? (a LT b) : FALSE ? d : e;
    a = (b GT c) ? (a LT b) : FALSE ? d : e;

    // a = MIN(1, 7);
    a = MIN(1, 7);

    // a = MAX( MIN(e, f), g);
    a = MAX( MIN(e, f), g);
}

Test output (truncated at top..)
We do not need to see all the #include <..> macro expansions.
...
Macro va_arg expands to: __crt_va_arg
Macro __crt_va_arg(args, int) expands to: ((sizeof(int)> sizeof(__int64)||(sizeof(int)&(sizeof(int)- 1))!= 0)? * *(int * *)((args += sizeof(__int64))- sizeof(__int64)):*(int *)((args += sizeof(__int64))- sizeof(__int64)))
Macro LOG("Argument %d: %d\n", i) expands to: printf("Argument %d: %d\n" ,i)
Macro va_end expands to: __crt_va_end
Macro __crt_va_end(args) expands to: ((void)(args=(va_list)0))
Macro MULTI_LINE_MACRO(1, 3) expands to: (((1)>(3))? pow((1),2):pow((3),3))
Macro KNOT_TO_MSEC(123.0) expands to: ((123.0)* 0.514444)
Macro STANDARD_GRAVITY expands to: (9.80665)
Macro LT expands to: <
Macro TRUE expands to: 1
Macro GT expands to: >
Macro GT expands to: >
Macro LT expands to: <
Macro FALSE expands to: 0
Macro MIN(1, 7) expands to: (((1)<=(7))?(1):(7))
Macro MAX(MIN, g) expands to: (((MIN)>(g))?(MIN):(g))
Macro MIN(e, f) expands to: (((e)<=(f))?(e):(f))
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TRUE                    1
#define FALSE                   0
#define SEMI                    ;
#define GT                      >
#define GE                      >=
#define LT                      <
#define LE                      <=
#define NE                      !
#define MIN(a, b)               (((a) <= (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MAX(a, b)               (((a) >  (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MULTI_LINE_MACRO(a, b)  (((a) > (b)) ?  \
                                /*LHS*/pow((a), 2) :   \
                                /*RHS*/pow((b), 3) )
#define KNOT_TO_MSEC(a)     ((a)*0.514444)
#define STANDARD_GRAVITY    (9.80665)
#define LON_LIMIT           180.0000241664
#define LAT_LIMIT           (LON_LIMIT/2.0)
#define LOG(format, ...)    printf(format, __VA_ARGS__)

void
variadicFunctionTest(int count, ...) {
    va_list args;
    __crt_va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int num = __crt_va_arg(args, int);
        printf("Argument %d: %d\n" ,i);
    }
    __crt_va_end(args);
}

void foo() {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    int t = 0;

    variadicFunctionTest(3, 1, 2, 3);

    // double bar = MULTI_LINE_MACRO(1, 3);
    double bar = (((1)>(3))? pow((1),2):pow((3),3));

    // double bar = KNOT_TO_MSEC(123.0) / STANDARD_GRAVITY;
    double foo = ((123.0)* 0.514444) / (9.80665);

    // a = b > c ? d : e;
    a = b > c ? d : e;

    // a = (b > c) ? (a LT b) ? c : d : TRUE;
    a = (b > c) ? (a < b) ? c : d : 1;

    // a = b GT c  ? d : e;
    a =  b > c  ? d : e;

    // a = (b GT c) ? (a LT b) : FALSE ? d : e;
    a = (b > c) ? (a < b) : 0 ? d : e;

    // a = MIN(1, 7);
    a = (((1)<=(7))?(1):(7));

    // a = MAX( MIN(e, f), g);
    a = (((MIN)>(g(((e)<=(f))?(e):(f))(g));
}


This is going to be a difficult question for someone to answer.  The thrust seems to be "help me implement a preprocessor" (or at least the macro expansion part), which is a tall order.  It would be difficult for an answer to be anything more than a code dump.  And, the motivation is questionable since the Clang preprocessor already does this; why not use (e.g.) Stmt::prettyPrint to emit based on its AST?

@ScottMcPeak The posted code is almost working but I cannot complete it as I cannot get the nesting to expand as expected. I've been struggling to solve this in so many ways without success.  I tried recursively calling MacroExpands but I don't know how to handle args/range parameters.  ChatGPT comes up with senseless suggestions.  I don't think I need a new preprocessor as I did most of the token pasting & stringifying (which already works), the thing that almost but does not quite work is handling nesting (expecially the order of nesting function like macros. Any help so appreciated.

@ScottMcPeak I've been really struggling with this whole macro expansion thing.  You indicated I might need a full preprocessor.  I wrote another question using boost::wave to expand the nested macros successfully but, I'm missing one little part of the puzzle there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78805360/how-to-use-boostwave-to-expand-nested-macros.  The idea is that if I can track the original ranges and corresponding ranges after expansion, I can use this info and pass it into clang's rewriter without having the rewriter corruption.  What do you think?

I don't know if this approach makes sense, and preprocessing is outside my areas of expertise (and I don't really want to be an expert at that if I can avoid it).  I too am working on an instrumentor, but I am not trying to preserve macros or comments since I just feed the output to a compiler and then discard it.
